# Ssh command to Windows machine via bash script executed from Jenkins slave

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, ssh, openssh

I'm have some bash script (`myscript.sh`), one of logical steps is to run `ssh` command against Windows machine running `open-ssh`.

When I'm running the script (`myscript.sh`) from the shell everything works fine. 
But when I am running same script from Jenkins (CentOS 7.3) it fails to retrieve content via `ssh` command: `ssh root@windows-server hostname`.

Please need your help.

Comment: Is there any error or other output in the Jenkins job's Console Log when "_it fails_"?

Comment: It's happening only when doing ssh against windows machines

Comment: No errors, ssh command finished with exit status 0

Answer (score 0):

The user running the jenkins process do probably not have the correct executable rights or group membership to do so.

Try

sudo -u "jenkinsuser" myscript.sh

If that fails you confirmed the issue.

Change the execute rights on your script or put the server process owner in the right group if this is the case.